# NHibernate / FluentNHibernate composite id camel case naming convention

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

Can someone direct me how to define a naming convention for CompositeId() in NHibernate?

I tried implementing `ICompositeIdentityConvention` (not working) :

```
public void Apply(ICompositeIdentityInstance instance)
{
    instance.Access.CamelCaseField(CamelCasePrefix.Underscore);
}
```

The other interfaces (`IPropertyInstance`, `IVersionInstance`, `IIdentityInstance`) has `instance.Column("Column name here");` method, but I can't find any on that interface.

I tried to loop through instance.KeyProperties with no result either.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this example helps to get you where you want to:

```
class CompositeKeyConvention : ICompositeIdentityConvention
{
    public void Apply(ICompositeIdentityInstance instance)
    {
        var columninspector = instance.KeyManyToOnes.First(k => k.Name == "Key").Columns.First();

        var columnmapping = (ColumnMapping)columninspector.GetType().GetField("mapping", BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(columninspector);

        columnmapping.Name = "IdColName";
    }
}
```